# Strips on Sentinel-1 EW image

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-1

I noticed some strips in a Sentinel-1 EW image acquired on 2015-03-30 over Lake Superior. This strips are visible only in HV band and are in the near range.

What are they and how can I get rid of them?

This is my code.

```
var geometry = ee.Geometry.Point([-89.90, 47.350])
Map.centerObject(geometry,7)
var water = ee.Image('JRC/GSW1_3/GlobalSurfaceWater');

var image = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S1_GRD")
          .filterBounds(geometry)
          .filterDate('2015-03-29','2015-04-01')
          .filter(ee.Filter.eq('instrumentMode','EW'))
          .filter(ee.Filter.eq('orbitProperties_pass', 'ASCENDING'))  
          .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'HH'))
          .select(['HH','HV','angle'])
          .mosaic()
          .updateMask(water.select('occurrence').gt(80))


Map.addLayer(image,{min:-20,max:0,bands:'HH'},'Sentinel-1 EW HH')
Map.addLayer(image,{min:-30,max:-5,bands:'HV'},'Sentinel-1 EW HV')
```

This is the image
[image]

This is the link to the script.
https://code.earthengine.google.com/a476c3dfd87741ff1c6cb6097942c7fa

Comment: Similar problem to this, by the look of it: https://forum.step.esa.int/t/thermal-noise-removal-of-sentinel-1-hv-pol-imagery-in-snap-software/12574/12